# iOS - Scrollview screenshot is showing grey parts

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
func takeScrollScreenshot() -> UIImage? {

    let scrollview: UIScrollView = self as! UIScrollView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollview.contentSize)
    let savedContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = scrollview.frame
    scrollview.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero;
    scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0),
                              y: CGFloat(0),
                              width: scrollview.contentSize.width,
                              height: scrollview.contentSize.height);
    scrollview.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    scrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
    scrollview.frame = savedFrame
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

The hierarchy is like this: View -> ScrollView -> View --> the remaining views

The scrollview screenshot, the problem is why the bottom part is not colored.

[image]

Screenshot of the inner view.

[image]

How should looks like

[image]

Comment: is your all view is subview of scrollview or you have container view which holds all the views ?

Comment: Is like this: View -> ScrollView -> View --> the remaining views

Comment: Then try to take screen shot of View (Subview of scrollview ) and check

Comment: I will try but the wierd thing is the same function is only failing in this screen

Comment: Yes !! . Your code has no problem . Even working for me also that's why I told you to use View

Comment: Lol, I did and i get a wierdest thing. I'm updating the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I just need add the line `drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)`

```
func takeScrollScreenshot() -> UIImage? {

    let scrollview: UIScrollView = self as! UIScrollView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollview.contentSize)
    let savedContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = scrollview.frame
    scrollview.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero;
    scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0),
                              y: CGFloat(0),
                              width: scrollview.contentSize.width,
                              height: scrollview.contentSize.height);
    scrollview.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    //I forget add this line.
    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    scrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
    scrollview.frame = savedFrame
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: after remove `scrollview.layer.render`  Only     `drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)` Working ?

Comment: I had to add it.